# How to send gmail from a nodejs application which is in azure cloud?

Tags: node.js, azure, angular6, nodemailer

Using nodemailer, Im able to send a mail in local. But in azure Im not able to send mail. I have given my code below:

```
    var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
     service: "gmail",
     auth: {
       user: 'xxx@gmail.com',
       pass: 'xx' 
     }
   });

  mailOptions={
    from: 'xxx@gmail.com',
    to : 'xxxx@gmail.com',
    subject : "Please confirm your Email account",
    text: 'Hello world?',
    html : "Hello,<br> Please Click on the link to verify your email.<br>Click here to verify"  
}
console.log(mailOptions);
smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, response){
 if(error){
        console.log(error);
    res.end("error");
 }else{
        console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
    res.end("sent");
     }
 });
```

Is this a right way or do i need to modify something to make this work in azure cloud? Could you please help me with this?

Im getting the following error in cloud:

```
   { Error: Invalid login: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin /continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbv9
 534-5.7.14     
534-5.7.14 i4B-3uDchhvH5tTH8yHwwR9VlDCAASd24gT6pvUq0R5bAUeoId> Please log             

in via
534-5.7.14 your web browser and then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754                             

l185sm50619884pfl.54 - gsmtp
at SMTPConnection._formatError (/home/Cello1/studio/node_modules 
/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:605:19)
at SMTPConnection._actionAUTHComplete (/home/Cello1/studio/node_modules
/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1340:34)
at SMTPConnection._responseActions.push.str (/home/Cello1/studio
/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:378:26)
at SMTPConnection._processResponse (/home/Cello1/studio/node_modules
/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:764:20)
at SMTPConnection._onData (/home/Cello1/studio/node_modules/nodemailer    
/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:570:14)
at TLSSocket._socket.on.chunk (/home/Cello1/studio
 /node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:710:55)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
code: 'EAUTH',
```

Comment: What error are you getting from `console.log(error)`?

Comment: @lagerone Im not getting any error in console. Also not getting the mail..

Comment: @lagerone I have updated the code with error.. Could you please check that?

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, I don't know what Azure service you used is.

If you were using Azure App Service (include Web Apps, Functions, etc), there is [some restrictions](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#networking-restrictionsconsiderations) you need to know, which may will cause your issue.

If you were using Azure VM or Container, please check your configuration for network outbound first. There seems to be [a similar issue](https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/564) in GitHub which may help you to try to authenticate with `oauth` for sending gmail.

Normally, the recommended way to send mail is using SendGrid service on Azure. You can refer to the offical document [`How to Send Email Using SendGrid from Node.js`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/store-sendgrid-nodejs-how-to-send-email) to know how to get started.